# How can I convert a double to a string without notation and with a high amount of accuracy in Java?

Tags: java, formatting

I'm trying to convert a double to a string without notation, and tried this:

```
f= Double.valueOf(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_VALUE)));  
NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("###.##############");
```

However, the value of 7^3^7 is returning as: 558546000000000000 opposed to 558545864083284007. As always help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "without notation"?

Comment: Notation as in the scientific notation or the E's.

Comment: If you want high precision numbers, consider using a BigDecimal rather than a double

Comment: Why not just use `long` values, if you're dealing with integers less than 19 decimal digits?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You already had the value as a String. Why convert it to double at all?
2. You can't get precision out of a double that it cannot hold. `558545864083284007` has 18 decimal digits. A `double` has 53 bits of binary precision, which is about 15.9 decimal digits. Google for 'What every computer scientist should know about floating-point'.
3. `###.##############` is not a suitable formatting mask for `558545864083284007`.

Comment: So then what should I us in place of a double to get the precision necessary?

Comment: I converted it as it was in a database which held it as a formatted double. What datatype would work for the precision I need. What would be then?

Comment: It should probably be a DECIMAL in the database, and a BigInteger or BigDecimal in Java.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the huge decimal number in string format, try using the `BigDecimal` class, something like this:

```
    BigDecimal bigDecimalValue = new BigDecimal("1234567890123456789012345678901234567890.54321");
    LOGGER.info("bigDecimalValue: {}", bigDecimalValue.toPlainString());
```

You should get back the original value with no precision loss:

```
bigDecimalValue: 1234567890123456789012345678901234567890.54321
```